# Como usar banco de dados Firebird na rede com C#?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, visual-studio-2013, firebird, redes

Desenvolvi uma aplicação C# Windows Forms com banco de dados Firebird e preciso colocar a aplicação com o banco em uma máquina que será tipo um servidor. Com isso, eu preciso acessar esse banco do servidor por outras máquinas que estarão na mesma rede. Como eu faço isso? O que é necessário configurar? Se alguém tiver algum link de tutorial para me mostrar.

Obrigado!

Comment: Eu não acho que você deveria fazer isso. Separe seus servidores Web do  servidor de banco de dados sempre que possível, mas se você TEM que assumir esse risco. Bem, nesse caso, supondo que sua aplicação já esteja funcionando, você só precisa configurar o computador como Web server para que outras pessoas tenham acesso à sua aplicação e aos conteúdo gerido por ela no banco de dados. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlDNct5lokA

Comment: @JohnDoe, a aplicação dele não é WEB. É uma aplicação desktop Windows Forms. Para resolver, você precisa colocar em cada máquina as DLLs de acesso ao Firebird. Além disso, no seu EXE, você deve apontar a string de conexão para o servidor aonde ficará o banco de dados. Depois que você identificar tudo que precisa para rodar numa maquina qualquer, faça um instalador pra facilitar.

Comment: Para conectar localmente uso uma string com esses parâmetros:

User=SYSDBA;
Password=masterkey; 
Database=C:\Banco\BANCO.fdb; 
DataSource=localhost; 
Port=3050; 
Dialect=3; 
Charset=WIN1252;
Role=; 
Connection lifetime=0;
Connection timeout=15;
Pooling=True;
PacketSize=16384;
Server Type=0;

Comment: @AndréMoraisMartins, não pode ser localhost. Você está usando Localhost, pois você está desenvolvendo na mesma máquina aonde o Firebird está rodando. Como você terá um cenário onde o Firebird vai rodar numa máquina e as outras terão acesso a ela, então sua string de conexão deve mudar. Seu DataSource, portanto, deverá ser o IP ou DNS da máquina aonde o FB está rodando.

Comment: Ops! Desculpa, pessoal!!!

Comment: Pessoal, fiz um teste aqui em uma outra aplicação e aparentemente funcionou! Na string de conexão troquei esses parâmetros:

Database=\Banco\BANCO.fdb;
DataSource=192.168.0.103;


Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @AndréMoraisMartins, postei uma resposta, favor verificar se atende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo, pois na string de conexão está sendo utilizado o **localhost**.

Utiliza-se **localhost** em casos aonde o banco de dados roda na mesma máquina da aplicação. É um cenário comum quando se está desenvolvendo.

Entretanto, o mais comum (e recomendado) é colocar o banco e a aplicação em máquinas distintas.

Assim, como o Firebird rodará numa máquina e as outras terão acesso a ela, a string de conexão deve mudar. O item DataSource da string de conexão, portanto, deverá apontar para o IP ou DNS da máquina aonde o FB executará.

Answer (score 0):

vc pode utilizar a seguinte string de conexão:

```
User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=c:\dados\meubanco.fdb;DataSource=NomeDoServidor;
Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;
MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;
```

onde:
`Database = caminho` caminho da base de dados no servidor
e
`DataSource = nome do servidor`, pode também utilizar o endereço IP do servidor.

você precisa instalar o Firebird em todas as maquinas que vão acessar o banco.